# How to make a scroller on a micro-processor/-controller?

Tags: c, embedded, scroll, microcontroller

I would like to write a text scroller on a micro-processor with 4 5x7 displays in ANSI-C.

Does anyone know of example source code or anything that can help me get started?

**Update**

[This](http://media.digikey.com/pdf/Data%20Sheets/ZiLOG%20PDFs/Z8%20Encore%20Dev.%20Kit%20Manual.pdf) is the user manual for the micro-processor board I have. On PDF page 17 is a picture of the board with the displays.

The code is written in an IDE called "zds2_Z8Encore493.exe" and then flashed to the micro-controller over serial port.

I would like the text to cascade from one to the next to the next column-by-column, so it is smooth.

Comment: It would help to know how the displays interface.  For example, if they are memory mapped, serial I/O, or register coordinate mapped.  Will you need cursor addressing or just raw text output?  Will all four displays contain the same output or do you want it cascaded from one to the next to the next?

Comment: I am new to this, but I have updated the info. Is that was you were asking for?

Comment: Did you read the first result of http://www.google.de/search?q=z8+encore+led ?

Answer (score 0):

There may be a better way, but I would store the text in a block of RAM, and in the routines that update the displays I would include a value to offset the starting point, possibly with a wrap-around to the start. The you store a counter which increments the "global" offset (scrolling).

You can then use `string[offset + display-width + scroll_position]` as the start pointer, but you need to detect the end and wrap round or just stop.